# Webpack 3 не работает компиляция scss

Tags: webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require ('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,

    entry : {
        common: './source/js/common.js'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('common.css')
    ]
}
```

Time: 133ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
common.js  2.53 kB       0  [emitted]  common
   [0] ./source/js/common.js 53 bytes {0} [built]

Не генерируется сss файл. 
Как посмотреть что плагин вообще запускается. Может логер есть какой нибудь?

Comment: Вы require в коде делаете? Насколько понимаю, без него вебпак просто проигнорирует файл.

Comment: require чего именно?

Comment: японя мать, вы были правы, нужно сам scss файл инклудить в js. Не понятно только зачем

Comment: А он иначе не работает. Почему никто не подумал о том, что собирать нужно не только JS - я не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливаем модуль:

```
npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

Подключаем:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
```

Ну и код модуля вынесенный в отдельный файл:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (paths) {
    return {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    include: paths,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        publicPath: '../',
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    include: paths,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: 'css-loader'
                    })
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/[name].css')
        ]
    };
};
```

Соедините с основным конфигом с помощью пакета "webpack-merge".
Если же не хотите выносить в отдельный файл то просто подключите в webpack.config.js и вставите:

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        publicPath: '../',
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: 'css-loader'
                    })
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/[name].css')
        ]
    };
```

Ну и не забудьте пути к вашим файлам подкорректировать.

Answer (score 1):

а вариант из документации Вам не подходит?

```
module.exports = {
    entry : './source/js/common.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "./public/js",
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        }]
    },
}
```

Comment: Не работает тоже

Comment: нужно style-loader в фолбек перенести чтобы работало.